# Adding varchar values along with Filetype in ASP Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

So I am trying to get my database to store in a value taken from a text box that carries the value of a session variable. When I try to add this in my database table demo which is this:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[demo]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
[email]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Name] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[ContentType] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[Data] VARBINARY(MAX) NULL
)
```

I get this exception:- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An explicit value for the identity column in table 'demo' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.'

Here is my aspx.cs code:-

```
    string constr = //My data Source
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text1.Text = "" + Session["email"];
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = INSERT INTO demo VALUES (@email, @Name, @ContentType, @Data);
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", text1.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any possible way I can get the textbox which is carrying session variable value into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the column names to your INSERT:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO demo (email, Name, ContentType, Data) VALUES (@email, @Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
```

Otherwise it will try to insert values into your Id column.

Comment: @JayModi Little tip: always, always specify column names for an insert